# SCID LaTex File

Tags: babel, chess

this is my first post, and I am using the chess program SCID to create some chess materials with LaTex. The following code is generated by SCID:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
% This is a LaTeX file generated by Scid.
% You must have the "chess12" package installed to typeset this file.

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{chess}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setlength{\columnsep}{7mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Macros for variations and diagrams:
\newenvironment{variation}{\begin{quote}}{\end{quote}}
\newenvironment{diagram}{\begin{nochess}}{$$\showboard$$\end{nochess}}

\begin{document}
{\bf
sample\\
}
\begin{chess}{\bf 
1.d4 d5 
    \begin{variation}
     1...Nf6 2.c4 e6 3.Nf3 d5 4.Nc3 Be7 5.Bf4 \end{variation}
    2.c4 e6 3.Nc3 Nf6 4.Nf3 Be7 5.Bf4 \begin{nochess}{\rm \#}\end{nochess} 
\begin{diagram}
\board{rnbqk* r}
 {ppp bppp}
 { * *pn *}
 {* *p* * }
 { *PP B *}
 {* N *N* }
 {PP *PPPP}
 {R *QKB*R}
\end{diagram}

}\end{chess}
{\bf *}
\begin{center} \hrule \end{center}

\end{document}
```

The generated pdf-file looks fine, but the following error messages are being shown:

[image]

I don't know what to do about that. Thank you for any help.

Regards
Michael

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) you can format code by indenting each line by four spaces or selecting all text and pressing the `{}` button.  The code you have seems ok, my guess is that the problem lies in `chess.sty` which is now 24 years old going by CTAN.  If this is the only option to export from SCID to LaTeX then you may need to manually edit the SCID output to make it compatible with another package like [`skak`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/skak), [`xskak`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xskak), or [`texmate`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texmate).

Comment: Could you use Scid vs pc?  If I remember correctly I've used the export to latex feature successfully in Scid vs pc.  Otherwise are you using the latest version of SCID?

Comment: You could try to add \usepackage[english]{babel} before loading chess (untested, I'm not at my PC currently). But it would be better if your system would modernize its export.

Comment: I am using Scid-4.6.2 (Ubuntu 14.04). So far I didn't succeed in installing scid vs pc on my computer. With Ulrike's advice the third message disappears, but the first two remain.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer's answer seems to work for me, I suspect this as good as you will be able to get.  It might be possible to put together an answer which explains how to go from the output to the `skak` package or similar (would you be interested in such an answer?) but I think at the end of the day this might be something to raise with the developers of Scid as their latex export feature really needs updating.

Comment: Scid's LaTeX export, has not been modified since 1999. If you consider that your pdf looks fine and can't modify Scid's LaTeX export, is preferable to leave it that way.

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of the errors by adding this your preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
% This is a LaTeX file generated by Scid.
% You must have the "chess12" package installed to typeset this file.

 %new
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\makeatletter \providecommand\babel@core@loaded{}\makeatother
\let\resetat\relax
% end new

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{chess}
```

But be aware that the chess package is very old and e.g. uses bitmap fonts. You would get a much better quality by using the xskak/chessboard package or texmate.

Comment: And `a4wide` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu you can install texlive-games and texlive-latex-extras, so there is no need to install the old fonts of package chess12.